# Cancel MUI Autocomplete onChange when reason is "create-option"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to be able to not allow a user to add an input value to Autocomplete's values array if an error exists with that value, but I also would like to preserve the input value currently being typed. Is there a way to cancel the event?

```
<Autocomplete
    multiple
    options={[]}
    freeSolo
    onChange={(event, value, reason) => {
        if (reason === 'create-option' && error) {
        // prevent this event from going through
        }
    }}
    ...
/>
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution to the question asked above per se, but solves my problem.

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      options={[]}
      freeSolo
      renderTags={(values: string[], getTagProps) => {
        return values.map((option: string, index: number) => {
          if (!option) return;
          return (
            <Chip
              variant="outlined"
              label={option}
              {...getTagProps({ index })}
            />
          );
        });
      }}
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onChange={(event: any, values: any, reason: string) => {
        if (reason === 'create-option' && form.getState().errors.verses) {
          setInputValue(values[values.length - 1]);
          values[values.length - 1] = null;
        } else {
          setInputValue('');
        }
      }}
/>
```

If you set `inputValue` on Autocomplete and then set the persisted value to null, you can preserve the input value without saving the undesired value so the user won't have to start typing all over again. If the value is valid, then set the input value to empty string.